# Simplificar código para mostrar/ocultar elementos de un html con js

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual muestra u oculta elementos de un html dependiendo del valor que se seleccione

HTML:

```
<div>
 <h3>Select Apples</h3>
<div>
<select id="apples" onchange="applenum()">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
function applenum() {
let apples = $("apples").val();
if (apples == "0") {
    $('#apple1').hide();
    $('#apple2').hide();
    $('#apple3').hide();
    $('#apple4').hide();
    $('#apple5').hide();
} else if (apples == "1") {
    $('#apple1').show();
    $('#apple2').hide();
    $('#apple3').hide();
    $('#apple4').hide();
    $('#apple5').hide();
} else if (apples == "2") {
    $('#apple1').show();
    $('#apple2').show();
    $('#apple3').hide();
    $('#apple4').hide();
    $('#apple5').hide();
}
}
```

¿Cómo puedo reducir el código con un bucle? ya que el número se incrementaría considerablemente dependiendo de la selección

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que el valor del `select #apples` indica "hasta" que `#apple[X]` hay que mostrar, podrías simplificar tu código así:

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function applenum() {
  let apples = parseInt($("#apples").val());
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $('#apple' + i)[i <= apples ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  }
}
$('apples').on('change', applenum);
applenum();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Select Apples</h3>
<div>
  <select id="apples" onchange="applenum()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="apple1">Apple 1</div>
<div id="apple2">Apple 2</div>
<div id="apple3">Apple 3</div>
<div id="apple4">Apple 4</div>
<div id="apple5">Apple 5</div>
```